# Turning on a latch circuit with a piezo sensor?

Tags: led, sensor, latch, piezo, schematic

I am trying to build a relatively 'simple' circuit with a piezo sensor that turns on an LED for ~10-20 seconds after it has been tapped.

In the off-state the circuit should use zero current to preserve battery life.
I would also like to avoid any ICs. Just some simple capacitors/resistors/mosfets etc.

I have tried a few different latch circuits - which seem to work fine with a normal button but I am not able to get them to work with the piezo sensor.

What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: Best is probably an MCU implementing a timer; some (MSP430 for example) can sleep at under 1 uA. Best within your constraints will take some design care to match that power consumption...

Comment: Zero current doesn't exist so be realistic.

Comment: Please provide technical information for your piezo sensor. There may be an easy way to do this.

Comment: It's a 20 mm piezo disc.

https://www.amazon.com/15-Pieces-20mm-Piezo-Elements/dp/B00A9AMHTI